# PHP - MYSQL - Delete duplicate rows but keep the last added

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

How to delete duplicate rows but to keep the last inserted.

### Table

```
Name   Surname   Value      Date
A        AA        2     2014-10-01
B        BB        5     2014-12-01
C        CC        9     2015-07-01
D        DD        9     2016-10-01
E        EE        9     2014-10-25
```

### Duplicate Values

```
Name   Surname   Value      Date
C        CC        9     2015-07-01
D        DD        9     2016-10-01
E        EE        9     2014-10-25
```

### Value that i want to keep

```
Name   Surname   Value      Date
D        DD        9     2016-10-01
```

---

The code updated after the answers, The goal is achieved.
Thanks to all respondents.
I hope this will be useful for someone.

### *Update*

```
    <?php
        include("conf.php");
        $table = "tables123";

        $query = "SELECT Name FROM " . $table;
        $resultat = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

        if(empty($resultat)) {
            echo "<p>" . $table . " table does not exist</p>";
            $query = mysqli_query($conn,"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table (
                Name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                Surname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                Value varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                Date varchar(255) NOT NULL
            )CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci");
        }
        else {
            echo "<p>" . $table . "table exists</p>";
        } // else

        $sql = "INSERT INTO $table (Name, Surname, Value, Date) 
        VALUES 
            ('A', 'AA', 2, '2014-10-01'), 
            ('B', 'BB', 5, '2014-12-01'), 
            ('C', 'CC', 9, '2015-07-01'), 
            ('D', 'DD', 9, '2016-10-01'),
            ('E', 'EE', 9, '2014-10-25')
            ";


        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }


        /// Hakan SONMEZ solution
        $sql3 = mysqli_query($conn, "
    DELETE tbl1 FROM $table tbl1, $table tbl2 WHERE tbl1.date < tbl2.date AND tb1.value = tb2.value
        ");

        ?>
```

Comment: Your question title is "Delete duplicate rows but keep the last added" and your SQL is SELECT. Is it irony?

Comment: I tried to get the duplicate names to filter by date and to delete , if you can get it.

Comment: Try my answer and you can delete them except latests.

Comment: Do you think your table name is new_table? You have to use your table name instead of new_table? Your table name is tables123. Just change only two strings in my query. Also I have edited your post about my query.

Comment: @HakanSONMEZ i updated the code but still i get the same results the same data in table.

Comment: I changed my solution to delete directly without selection, please try it now

Comment: @Jayvee i updated but still no success, do i do a correct implemention ?

Comment: what's the incorrect result when you run it?

Comment: @Jayvee there is no error but in the table the results are the same the duplicate rows are not removed.

Comment: maybe is not committing, try adding a mysqli_commit

Comment: @Jayvee i updated your code on the question and i get an error.

Comment: it should be mysqli_commit($conn);

Comment: There are syntax error. Your tables aliases are tbl1 and tbl2 not tb1 and tb2. Sorry dude. Also I have edited your post again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]Try this.

```
DELETE tbl1 FROM new_table tbl1, new_table tbl2 WHERE tbl1.date < tbl2.date AND tbl1.value = tbl2.value;
```

Edit: Copy your data before you try.

Answer (score 0):

something on these lines should work:

```
delete t from table t 
join (select value, max(Date) maxdate, from table group by value) as t1
on t.value=t1.value 
where date<maxdate
```