# How to delete duplicate data from MySQL except latest data

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete, delete-row

I want to `delete` records from `mysql` table

I have table like this

I am checking here if **(date, url, price, hotelName)** is same then remove except one

```
id | hotelName | price | url      | date        |
-------------------------------------------------
1  | abcd      | 20$   | abcd.com | 21 jan 2019 |
2  | abcd      | 24$   | abcd.com | 22 jan 2019 |
3  | wzyz      | 10$   | wzyz.com | 21 jan 2019 |
4  | abcd      | 20$   | abcd.com | 21 jan 2019 |
5  | wzyz      | 15$   | wzyz.com | 22 jan 2019 |
6  | wzyz      | 15$   | wzyz.com | 22 jan 2019 |
```

In this table you can see duplicate records is id [1,4] and [5,6]

I want to delete duplicate records from this table except latest data

After deleting this table should look like

```
id | hotelName | price | url      | date        |
-------------------------------------------------
2  | abcd      | 24$   | abcd.com | 22 jan 2019 |
3  | wzyz      | 10$   | wzyz.com | 21 jan 2019 |
4  | abcd      | 20$   | abcd.com | 21 jan 2019 |
6  | wzyz      | 15$   | wzyz.com | 22 jan 2019 |
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - MYSQL - Delete duplicate rows but keep the last added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39838226/php-mysql-delete-duplicate-rows-but-keep-the-last-added)

Comment: no it is diffrent

Comment: If you don't believe it's a duplicate you need to edit your question to explain in detail how it is different from the other question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your table is not too big, this is a short and straight-forward syntax :

```
DELETE t1 
FROM 
    mytable t1 
    CROSS JOIN t2 
WHERE 
    t1.id < t2.id 
    AND t1.hotelName = t2.hotelName 
    AND t1.date      = t2.date
    AND t1.url       = t2.url
    AND t1.price     = t2.price
```

Anoter solution, less resource-consuming :

```
DELETE FROM mytable
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT MAX(t.id) FROM mytable t GROUP BY t.hotelName, t.date, t.url, t.price
)
```

Comment: my table is big more then 150K records

Comment: this query will delete id [1,2,3,5] records 

i only want to delete 1 and 5 id records

Comment: @ajaykumbhare sorry I was missing a column in the `GROUP BY` clause... Fixed.

Comment: GROUP BY t.hotelName, t2.date

t.date ?

Comment: `GROUP BY t.hotelName, t.date`

Comment: i tried this query but it is deleting id 3 records also 

SELECT id from mytable WHERE id not in (SELECT MAX(t.id) as id FROM mytable t GROUP BY t.hotelName, t.date)

Comment: i am checking here if **(date,url,price,hotelName)** is same then remove except one

Comment: OK @ajaykumbhare so you need to add all those conditions to the `GROUP BY` clause

Comment: "my table is big more then 150K records" Sorry to say 150K records isn't big

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend `group by` and `join` for this purpose:

```
delete t join
       (select date, url, price, hotelName, max(id) as max_id
        from t
        group by date, url, price, hotelName
       ) tt
       using (date, url, price, hotelName)
    where t.id < tt.max_id;
```

I assume by latest, you mean "keep the one with the largest id".

If you have a large amount of data, `delete` can be expensive.  In that case. `create temporary table`/`truncate`/`insert` might have better performance.